# Store data and global variables using the Application object

Tags: android, class, xamarin, global-variables

In Xamarin, I am wanting to store data and global variables using the Application object.

I looked at this resource for this code:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state

Here is my code:

```
    public class HelloApplication : Application 
    {
        private int GlobalVariable = 1;

        public int GetGlobalVariable()
        {
            return GlobalVariable;
        }

        public void SetGlobalVariable(int GlobalVariable)
        {
            this.GlobalVariable = GlobalVariable;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to reference the class using this code:

```
    ((HelloApplication)GetApplication()).setGlobalVariable(10);
    int variable=((HelloApplication)GetApplication()).getGlobalVariable();
```

When I build the application I am getting this error for both the above lines of code:

> The name 'GetApplication' does not exist in the current context

Can I please have some help to get this code working?

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
HelloApplication state = ((HelloApplication) this.ApplicationContext);
state.SetGlobalVariable(10);
int globalVariable = state.GetGlobalVariable ();

Toast.MakeText (this, "Global variable " + globalVariable, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
```

This is the error I am getting:

> UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Comment: you can try `HelloApplication state = ((HelloApplication) getApplicationContext());  state.setGlobalVariable(10); int variable= state.getGlobalVariable();` see if this works.

Comment: try ((HelloApplication) this.getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(10);

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code you could just make the variable a public static.

```
public class HelloApplication : Application 
{
    public static int GlobalVariable = 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
HelloApplication.GlobalVariable = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
((HelloApplication)GetApplication())
```

to

```
((HelloApplication)GetApplicationContext())
```