# How to declare global variables or constants in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

As I continue to work on and debug my hobby app to learn/practise Xamarin Android devt, I discovered I produced a version that could be installed on my phone, but it could not be run. (After successful installation, only the Done button could be pressed, the Open button was grayed out)

[s'shot of Open button that is grayed out when the public static class is added in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBcus.jpg)

There were a few changes since the last version that could be run, and having narrowed it down, the problem is the definition of a public static class in order to define some global variables.

```
public static class GlobalVariables1
    {
        public static string TdyAlertTime1 = "11";
        public static string TdyAlertTime2 = "15";
        public static string TdyAlertTime3 = "21";
    }
```

This was adopted having followed [How to declare global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686089/how-to-declare-global-variable). I have tried making adjustments to that but still not resolving.

I also tried other methods found on the Net to no avail:

[Store data and global variables using the Application object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494238/store-data-and-global-variables-using-the-application-object)

```
public class HelloApplication : Application 
{
    public static int GlobalVariable = 1;
}
```

I also saw SharedPreferences and Application Properties Dictionary but the latter seemed applicable for certain functions eg. OnStart; and the former, I had poor experience before when trying to develop a Preferences screen.

But back to my original intention. I want to define simple global variables or constants (actually for debugging purposes currently, but learning it would be useful for other purposes too) to be utilised in two different classes in my project.

What could be wrong with the method I adopted (to cause the inability to run)? Or what method could I really use in a simple manner?

Thanx & Rgds

Comment: "I have tried making adjustments to that but still not resolving." - what does this mean?  What specifically is not working when you try this approach?

Comment: arbitrary hit-and-miss attempts like removing "static" and changing public to private, etc.
Not working meaning the Run button still remains grayed out

Comment: what is the "Run button"?  You didn't include any UI code in your post.

Comment: Oops, it should be the Open button. The ones that appear at the bottom right corner after APK installation. I shall edit the question and see if I can upload a s'shot

Comment: I still have no idea what you're doing.  You haven't shown any relevant code.  Is the Open button part of your app's UI, or is this an Android dialog that appears after app installation?  And in the screenshot you posted, the Open button appears to be active to me.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for responding.
1. The code being the 'public static class' is the offending code that I had identified to be the culprit >> Question: why does this cause the 'Open' button to be grayed out
2. Maybe I have been presumptuous due to my inexperience that that s'shot I added is a standard screen after installation of any APK. Indeed, in the s'shot the Open button is fine. But in my case, when the 'public static class' is added in the code, it becomes grayed out. i.e APK can be installed , but cannot be run/opened

Comment: if your app won't run, you need to look at the device logs, or attempt to run it directly from the IDE.